# MySQL Grouping to Display Zero Records

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have an Intranet site that only registered users can watch videos. Users can watch videos on several platforms like iPhone, iPad, Android or Web and I track all those information (for the simplicity of the problem, please do not consider other platforms). I am trying to display some video watch reports at admin panel.

Table structure is below (I have lots of other columns but they are not important for this problem);

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `history` (
  `history_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `video_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `platform_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`history_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;

INSERT INTO `history` (`history_id`, `video_id`, `user_id`, `platform_id`, `created`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 1, '2012-05-06 08:13:57'),
(2, 2, 1, 1, '2012-05-06 13:23:57'),
(3, 1, 1, 4, '2012-05-06 18:16:39'),
(4, 4, 2, 3, '2012-05-07 08:14:19'),
(5, 1, 2, 3, '2012-05-07 08:14:55'),
(6, 2, 1, 1, '2012-05-07 15:14:55'),
(7, 3, 2, 1, '2012-05-07 18:05:14'),
(8, 3, 1, 4, '2012-05-07 18:15:24');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sys_list_of_values` (
  `value_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `display_text` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `list_value` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `list_group` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`value_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

INSERT INTO `sys_list_of_values` (`value_id`, `display_text`, `list_value`, `list_group`) VALUES
(1, 'iPhone', 'iphone', 'platform'),
(2, 'Android', 'android', 'platform'),
(3, 'iPad', 'ipad', 'platform'),
(4, 'Website', 'web', 'platform'),
(5, 'Active', 'active', 'status'),
(6, 'Passive', 'passive', 'status'),
(7, 'Waiting for approvement', 'waiting', 'status'),
(8, 'Spam', 'spam', 'status'),
(9, 'Deleted', 'deleted', 'status');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `username`) VALUES
(1, 'test_user_1'),
(2, 'test_user_2');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `videos` (
  `video_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `status` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`video_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

INSERT INTO `videos` (`video_id`, `user_id`, `title`, `created`, `status`) VALUES
(1, 1, 'Test Video 1', '2012-05-07 08:12:52', 7),
(2, 1, 'Test Video 2', '2012-05-07 08:12:52', 5),
(3, 1, 'Test Video 3', '2012-05-07 08:13:17', 5),
(4, 1, 'Test Video 4', '2012-05-07 08:13:17', 6);
```

I am trying to display a report like below;

```
Platform      |     Watch_Count
===============================
iPhone                  20
iPad                     0
Android                  2
Website                120
Total                  142
```

I have some filter options, like `video_id`, `created`, `platform` etc. For example; I want to display a total watch report for all videos, or for a specific video (video_id), or between dates (created) etc. I also want to display all platforms, whether they are 0 or anything.

The following query displays only iPhone and Website, but I want to display all platforms. If there are no watch count, then it has to be displayed as 0 (zero). I also can't display a final row which sums all `watch_count`s and displays a total.

```
SELECT sys_list_of_values.display_text, COUNT(history.history_id) AS 'total_watch' FROM history
JOIN sys_list_of_values ON sys_list_of_values.value_id = history.platform_id
WHERE history.video_id = 1
AND history.created <  '2012-05-07'
GROUP BY history.platform_id
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retaining your `FROM HISTORY`, change your `JOIN` to `RIGHT JOIN`

```
SELECT sys_list_of_values.display_text, COUNT(history.history_id) AS 'total_watch' 
FROM history
RIGHT JOIN sys_list_of_values 
   ON sys_list_of_values.value_id = history.platform_id
   AND history.created <  '2012-05-07'
   AND history.video_id = 1

GROUP BY sys_list_of_values.value_id 
order by sys_list_of_values.display_text;
```

If you want to use `LEFT JOIN`, switch the places of history and sys_list_of_values:

```
SELECT sys_list_of_values.display_text, COUNT(history.history_id) AS 'total_watch' 
FROM sys_list_of_values 
LEFT JOIN history
   ON sys_list_of_values.value_id = history.platform_id
   AND history.created <  '2012-05-07'
   AND history.video_id = 1

GROUP BY sys_list_of_values.value_id 
order by sys_list_of_values.display_text;
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/495d1/15

---

GROUP BY with ROLLUP is incompatible with ORDER, anyway ROLLUP automatically sorts the list, just remove the ORDER:

```
SELECT sys_list_of_values.display_text, 
  -- sys_list_of_values.value_id,
  COUNT(history.platform_id) AS 'total_watch' 
FROM sys_list_of_values 
LEFT JOIN history
   ON sys_list_of_values.value_id = history.platform_id
   AND history.created <  '2012-05-07'
   AND history.video_id = 1

where sys_list_of_values.list_group = 'platform'
GROUP BY 
 sys_list_of_values.display_text with rollup
```

Live test: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/495d1/68

Comment: Thank you Michael, this works (almost) perfect. I just wanted to display a final row and that row will give me the grand total. If I use `GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP`, the `ORDER BY` produces and error. If there is a workaround to use `GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP` and `ORDER BY`, I'd happily accept your answer.

Comment: Btw another 'thank you' for informing me such a great site, SQL Fiddle :)

Comment: @BurakErdem it's ok now, try it again. You can also paste tabular data in SqlFiddle and it will automatically create a `CREATE TABLE` statement for you. Example, copy the grid in your **I am trying to display a report like below;**, then paste it to SqlFiddle's Text to DDL, it will automatically create a DDL for you. Just remove the pipe `|` sign :-)  If you have pipe sign in header, the data should have a pipe in between them

Comment: Anyway, SqlFiddle's Text to DDL is pretty heuristic, it can accept CSV, semicolon-delimited, space-delimited(as long as the data has no space in them), table results from MySQL/Postgresql commandline, etc. It can also tell you if the header doesn't match the rows format. You can almost create a DDL out of any text data with SqlFiddle :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `LEFT JOIN` and move the conditions that involve the "right" table from the `WHERE` to the `ON`:

```
SELECT s.display_text
     , COUNT(h.history_id) AS total_watch 
FROM 
    sys_list_of_values AS s 
  LEFT JOIN 
    history AS h
      ON  h.platform_id = s.value_id 
      AND h.video_id = 1
      AND h.created <  '2012-05-07'
GROUP BY s.value_id
  WITH ROLLUP                     --- for an additional final row with total sum
```

If you want `ORDER BY display_text` and `ROLLUP`, use this:

```
GROUP BY s.display_text
  WITH ROLLUP
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join the counts against the list of platforms using a subquery:

```
SELECT display_text, IFNULL(total_watch, 0)
FROM sys_list_of_values
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT platform_id AS value_id, COUNT(history_id) AS total_watch
    FROM history
    WHERE video_id = 1
    AND history.created < '2012-05-07'
    GROUP BY platform_id
) AS watch_counts USING (value_id)
WHERE list_group = 'platform'
```

By the way, it's usually more performant to complete the list of platforms in the application code rather than doing it in the DB, especially if one assumes the application code has a long-lived cache of all existing platforms at hand.

Comment: Thanks Romain but this query produces an error; `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE list_group = 'platform'`

Comment: Doh - my bad, sorry, fixed answer - was missing USING clause.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  sys_list_of_values.value_id     as VID,
  sys_list_of_values.display_text,
  COUNT(history.history_id)       AS 'total_watch'
FROM sys_list_of_values
   JOIN history
    ON sys_list_of_values.value_id = history.platform_id
where sys_list_of_values.list_group = 'platform'
    and history.created < '2012-05-07'
GROUP BY history.platform_id
order by VID
```

Comment: Thanks but this query still displays only `iPhone` and `Website` but not `Android` nor `iPad`.

Comment: because i have put the date here in where clause try your own conditions as how you need data if you need a/c to date use date condition if platform use platform condition and if video id then use video id in where